# I want to fetch and insert an attribute multiple times

Tags: javascript

I want to fire the contents of all attributes in a custom element `<my-component>` . Currently, only the preceding attribute is executed.

If it works, this will be `<p>hello, world! welcom </p>` .

Also, I want the {{ }} part to be executed with or without spaces.

```js
function component(elementName, ComponentOptions) {
  customElements.define(`${elementName}`, class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      if (ComponentOptions.return) {
        if (this.getAttributeNames()) {
          const AttrNames = this.getAttributeNames();
          var optionsreturn = ComponentOptions.return;
          AttrNames.forEach(attr => {
            let val = this.getAttribute(attr);
            optionsreturn = optionsreturn.replace(`{{ ${attr} }}`, val);
            this.outerHTML = optionsreturn;
          });
        } else {
          this.outerHTML = ComponentOptions.return
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

component("my-component", {
  return: `<p>hello, {{ w }} {{ wel }} </p>`
})
```

```html
<my-component w="world!" wel="welcom"></my-component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `this.outerHTML = optionsreturn;` outside the `forEach` loop.

I also changed the string into a regular expression in your `.replace()` call. It will now accept zero or one spaces surrounding your attribute names.

```js
function component(elementName, ComponentOptions) {
  customElements.define(elementName, class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      if (ComponentOptions.return) {
        if (this.getAttributeNames()) {
          const AttrNames = this.getAttributeNames();
          var optionsreturn = ComponentOptions.return;
          AttrNames.forEach(attr => {
            let val = this.getAttribute(attr);
            optionsreturn = optionsreturn.replace(new RegExp(`\{\{ ?${attr} ?\}\}`,"g"), val);
          });
          this.outerHTML = optionsreturn;
        } else {
          this.outerHTML = ComponentOptions.return
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

component("my-component", {
  return: `<p>hello, {{ w }} {{wel}} </p>`
})
```

```html
<my-component w="world!" wel="welcom"></my-component>
```